# ruby cannot find jiveapp gem although i installed it

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I searched through similar questions, but still could not solve this problem.  I installed my jiveapps gem, but then it cannot be found.

```
Successfully installed jiveapps-1.0.7
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for jiveapps-1.0.7...
Installing RDoc documentation for jiveapps-1.0.7...
new-host-2:sites jeffreyerickatz$ gem list jiveapps

*** LOCAL GEMS ***
```

The following also did not work:

```
new-host-2:sites jeffreyerickatz$ gem which jiveapps
ERROR:  Can't find ruby library file or shared library jiveapps
new-host-2:sites jeffreyerickatz$ rake gemspec
rake aborted!
No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

You can see that I only have one version of ruby installed

```
ew-host-2:sites jeffreyerickatz$ rvm list

rvm rubies

=* ruby-1.9.3-p194 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

and here are my gem paths

```
 - GEM PATHS:
 - /Users/jeffreyerickatz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
 - /Users/jeffreyerickatz/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
```

and when I do sudo gem environment I get

```
sudo gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
 - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.24
 - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2012-04-20 patchlevel 194) [x86_64-darwin11.4.2]
 - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/jeffreyerickatz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-  p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
 - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/jeffreyerickatz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
 - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/jeffreyerickatz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin
 - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-11
 - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/jeffreyerickatz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
     - /Users/jeffreyerickatz/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
 - :update_sources => true
 - :verbose => true
 - :benchmark => false
 - :backtrace => false
 - :bulk_threshold => 1000
- REMOTE SOURCES:
   - http://rubygems.org/
```

gem path

```
new-host-2:Desktop jeffreyerickatz$ echo $GEM_HOME
/Users/jeffreyerickatz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194
```

Comment: Include the output of 'gem environment' as well

Answer (score 0):

If you copied pasted that correctly, it looks like gems are being installed into "/Users/jeffreyerickatz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-   p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1" (note the space between 1.9.3- and p194).

You can further check by `echo $GEM_HOME`. $GEM_HOME should be set to your gem path.